# SQL- Calculating average of differences between times

Tags: sql-server

I have an sql table that has transaction history of all the clients. I want to find what is the average difference in time between two transactions.

```
ClientCode      Date
DL2xxx          2016-04-18 00:00:00.000
DL2xxx          2016-04-18 00:00:00.000
E19xxx          2016-04-18 00:00:00.000
E19xxx          2016-04-18 00:00:00.000
E19xxx          2016-04-18 00:00:00.000
JDZxxx          2016-04-18 00:00:00.000
```

Given above are the first few lines of the table the date given is the date transaction happened. I want to take an average of difference in days when successive transactions happen. Say for a client he makes transactions of Day 1, Day 3, Day 10, and Day 15. So differences are {2, 7, 5} average of which is 4.66. If only one transaction takes place this should be 0.

```
ClientCode AverageDays
DL2xxx     <float_value>
DL2xxx     <float_value>
E19xxx     <float_value>
```

This is what the output should look like where each unique client code occurs only once.

Comment: Ca you add sample output and input data

Comment: I have added more details inform me if you find this insufficient.

Comment: If performance is an issue, can you provide info on what indexes are on the table?

Comment: What are indexes? There are no unique identifiers in this table. Rest of the table contains value of transaction, taxes, product, quantity etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windowing functions aren't available to you, here's an alternative

```
--CREATE SAMPLE DATA
CREATE TABLE #TMP(ClientID INT, EventDate DATE)
GO

INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES
(1,DATEADD(DD,RAND()*365,'20180101'))
,(2,DATEADD(DD,RAND()*365,'20180101'))
,(3,DATEADD(DD,RAND()*365,'20180101'))
,(4,DATEADD(DD,RAND()*365,'20180101'))
,(5,DATEADD(DD,RAND()*365,'20180101'))
GO 50


--PRE SQL 2012 Compatible
SELECT A.ClientID
        ,AVG(DATEDIFF(DD,C.EventDate,A.Eventdate)) AS ClientAvg

 FROM #TMP A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT ClientID, MAX(EventDate) EventDate FROM #TMP B
                    WHERE A.ClientID = B.ClientID AND A.EventDate > B.EventDate
                    GROUP BY ClientID) C
GROUP BY A.ClientID
ORDER BY A.ClientID
```

Comment: Does this give $0$ if there is only 1 transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like below if you table name is T
<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/TTXW84875)**</kbd>

```
select 
ClientCode, 
AvgDays =ISNULL(AVG(d),0)
from
(
    select 
        *, 
        d=DATEDIFF(
                d,
                dateofT,
                LEAD(DateofT) over( 
                        partition by ClientCode 
                        order by DateofT asc )) 
    from t
)t
group by ClientCode
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAG()` function to compare a date to it's previous date by client, then group by client and calculate the average.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Transactions') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Transactions

CREATE TABLE #Transactions (
    ClientCode VARCHAR(100),
    Date DATE)

INSERT INTO #Transactions (
    ClientCode,
    Date)
VALUES
    ('DL2', '2016-04-18'),
    ('DL2', '2016-04-19'),
    ('DL2', '2016-04-26'),

    ('E19', '2016-01-01'),
    ('E19', '2016-01-11'),
    ('E19', '2016-01-12')


;WITH DayDifferences AS
(
    SELECT
        T.ClientCode,
        T.Date,
        DayDifference = DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            LAG(T.Date) OVER (PARTITION BY T.ClientCode ORDER BY T.Date ASC),
            T.Date)
    FROM
        #Transactions AS T
)
SELECT
    D.ClientCode,
    AverageDayDifference = AVG(ISNULL(CONVERT(FLOAT, D.DayDifference), 0))
FROM
    DayDifferences AS D
GROUP BY
    D.ClientCode
```

Comment: So this will create a DayDifference query and then take the average from that table right? Among your and dhruvjoshi's answer which is faster as I have to run this for an extremely large table

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar both queries are similar and should yield similar performance. You might want to create an index on ClientCode, Date before running.

Answer (score 0):

Using the observation that the sum of differences within a group is simply the `max - min` of that group, you can use the simple group by select:

```
select IIF(COUNT(*) > 1, 
(CAST(DATEDIFF(day, MIN(DateofT), MAX(DateofT)) AS FLOAT)) / (COUNT(*) - 1), 0.0) 
AS AVGDays, ClientCode 
FROM t GROUP BY ClientCode
```